# How can we stop thread

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, ios4, nsrunloop

I am developing application in which my thread is starting when connectionDidFinishLoading.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [downloadingthread cancel];
    downloadingthread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startusingthread) object:nil];
    [downloadingthread start];
}
```

connectionDidFinishLoading is called multiple times, so I want to stop download thread and then start agin it again. I am trying to execute last thread only. Please help me to stop my thread in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never stop a thread by force.

You stop the request using `-[NSURLConnection cancel]`.

Your thread should be on a run loop, so you would cancel the run loop for that thread if you are aborting the request but... it's very expensive to create threads all over the place, and there is often a better alternative to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reaply but i am thinking that if we can play with thread as we want than we can do many things in iPhone.like our application is one type of thread in iPhone,And we can stop it when we are want,So ultimately main thread is stop in-between.So,may be we can also stop thread in between.

Comment: By 'stop-in-between', I believe you are referring to the thread's run loop. A run loop runs, then rests, then resumes at a specified time interval. Telling the run loop to stop is safe - I mentioned it in my answer. Stopping a run loop is not immediate (by force), it waits until the thread is entering or exiting an idle state. You can install timers and send messages to be performed by the run loop. This is a good, safe approach.